# Javascript within Joomla Module

Tags: joomla

I am new to Joomla and have been able to do all I wanted until the point I needed to add some Javascript to a module.
The code below only produces "Test1" and "Test2", but no alert pops up.
What am I missing?

```
<div>
TEST1
<script type="text/javascript">
alert 'alert';
</script>
TEST2
</div>
```

Comment: Your js is wrong, read this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div>
TEST1
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("alert");
</script>
TEST2
</div>
```

Comment: In joomla's article javascript will not work. You need to write javascript code in your custom js file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sourcer](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer) plugin from [nonumber.nl](https://www.nonumber.nl)